# Why there is no module exit function for android binder driver

Tags: android

In binder. c init function is defined but no exit function.
In init part misc_register() is called. The same should be deregistered in module exit by calling 
Misc_deregister() function. Can anyone help me to understand why no module exit function for android binder driver?

Comment: There is binder.c( drivers/staging/android/binder.c). In binder_init() function misc_register(&binder_miscdev) is called.

Comment: so where should "deregister" be called? what line in [binder.c](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/+/android-msm-hammerhead-3.4-kk-r1/drivers/staging/android/binder.c)?

Comment: In module_exit(). But not there. Every driver has module init and exit function. For this why it is not there. In module exit clean up should be done.

Comment: binder module is built into the kernel, and not loadable, isnt it?